# React component structure benefit and two way binding drawback

Tags: reactjs

I have some queries about the component structure of React:

- Writing both HTML and code logic in render method makes the code complex, Isn't it?
- In React, data flows only from up to down. Why doesn't react support two-way binding? What are the drawbacks of the same?

Answer (score 0):

- I don't see what's more complex about having "HTML" mixed with JavaScript. The alternative seems to be an entirely separate template language that mixes a very different and usually much more limited syntax for logic with HTML. I can't see how that can in any way be perceived as less complex. You could argue that there's less separation of concerns with (idiomatic) React, but then why not just put the rendering logic in a different file? It's just JavaScript, you can organize it how you want.
- Two-way bindings are very complex and hard to debug. Even one-way bindings are hard because there's so much indirection involved. But React doesn't have one-way bindings in the traditional sense either. Conceptually it's just pure(-ish) function calls with argument passing that returns a new "DOM"-tree whenever something changes. This simplicity makes it much easier to manage complexity, and to debug issues, since you don't have to trace state changes to understand what's happening.